# How to  reload a  jqGrid with new xmlstring data constructed on the client-side

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Initially the jGrid is sucesfully loaded  with xmlstring data.
Then I am using custom code to allow the user to filter the data of the Grid.

A new xml string is constructed and I am trying to feed this to the jGrid and force a reload using:

`('#adsGrid').jqGrid('setGridParam',{datastr:adsStrNew}).trigger("reloadGrid");`

However the data remains the same, although the new xml adsStrNew is correct and different to the original one, does .trigger("reloadGrid"), take the new passed parameter into account(adsStrNew) or it uses the original datastr?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by including `dataype: "xmlstring"` in setGridParam.